# Guidance on tracking time user have watched video stream using google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am building a site where admin will stream their desktop screen using WebRTC and site users have a button which they press and stream starts and they can view the video stream. 
I want to use google analytics to track following but no idea what the best way is to approach the requirements

Note: Each site user may be a direct or via referral site.

What we want to track is:

1) How long each user have viewed the video over a timeframe 1 day, 7 day etc?

2) Users need to be tagged as per their referral

3) How long stream was watched by users of each referral.

Idea behind this so that we can contact each referral and show them their users are being active and they can advertise their products to them.